# Query that also get name, the popdensity, and state, "not a group by expression"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to get this query to work, I know I'm close. I'm trying to get the name of the one city for each state, and the population density of that city. ^

The subquery is correct as it gets the most recent data from a population table for the city. The query currently returns a "not a group by expression,"

If I remove `s.name`, it works correctly and I get the correct data to match with the state value, but I don't have the name.  But if I add the name, it no longer works, and if I add the `s.name` to the group by expression, I get all the city for the state which isn't want I'm trying to get.

How do I modify this so I can get the name, but still only have one data point for each state, while also getting the most recent population?

```
SELECT s.name, MAX(ROUND(p.population / s.area, 2)), e.encompasses_state
  FROM city s
  LEFT JOIN state e
    ON s.code = e.code
  LEFT JOIN citypopulations p
    ON p.code = s.code
 WHERE p.rowid IN (SELECT MAX(rowid) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY year, population )
                     FROM citypopulations px
                    WHERE s.code = px.code)
 GROUP BY e.encompasses_state;
```

Tables:

City:

| name | code | area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LA | OH | 50 |
| new york | WI | 100 |

State:

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Ohio | OH |
| Wisconsin | WI |

Citypop:

| code | Year | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new york | 1998 | 10000 |
| new york | 2000 | 10000 |
| new york | 1998 | 6000 |
| new york | 1978 | 8000 |
| LA | 1999 | 2000 |
| LA | 2000 | 20000 |
| LA | 2000 | 5000 |

Answer (score 1):

You'll need another KEEP/DENSE_RANK or similar aggregation.  Within the grouping of a given "encompasses_state", there are potentially multiple "state" values, so you need to decide which one you want.

If its "any" one, ie, you don't care, then just add an aggregation, eg

```
select 
  max(s.name), 
  max(round( p.population / s.area, 2)), 
  e.encompasses_state
...
group by 
  e.encompasses_state
```

If you want the state that is the one that has the maximum population/area, then a KEEP can handle that

```
select 
  max(s.name) KEEP ( dense_rank last order by p.population / s.area ), 
  max(round( p.population / s.area, 2)), 
  e.encompasses_state
...
group by 
  e.encompasses_state
```